# Proving divergence by using comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I want to prove the divergence of the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n + \ln^2{n}}$$

At first, I tried to find another series who is always smaller to be able to prove that the series diverges by the comparison test.
$$\frac{1}{n+\ln^2{n}} > \frac{1}{n+n^2} > \frac{1}{2n^2}$$

But, the resulting series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. And I know that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n + \ln^2{n}}$ diverges.

Where my reasoning went wrong!?

Comment: Is $x$ a constant?

Comment: @lulu My mistake. Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Hint:  for large $n$, $log(n)≤\sqrt n$.

Comment: @lulu So, rather than replace $\ln^2{n}$ by $n^2$, I should replace it by $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: You probably mean $\ln^2 n$. I might use limit comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n}$. What went wrong is that you gave too much away. From a series is bigger than a converging series we cannot conclude anything.

Comment: Well, you can.  But my hint suggested replacing $ln(n)$ by $\sqrt n$, hence replacing $ln^2(n)$ by $n$

Comment: @AndréNicolas Which algebric manipulations would you do to get the final serie $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Informally, the $\ln^2 n$ term is in the long run negligible compared to $n$. For the formal part, I would take the limit of $\frac{1/(n+\ln^2 n)}{1/n}$. But comparisons are good too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may observe that, as $n \to \infty$,

> $$
>  \frac{1}{n + \ln^2{n}}\sim   \frac{1}{n}\times\frac{1}{1 + \frac{\ln^2{n}}n} \sim \frac1n
> $$

giving, by using **comparison test**, the **divergence** of your initial series.

Comment: I didn't thnik about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For  $n\geq 5$, $\ln n \leq \sqrt n$ and hence we have $\frac {1}{(\ln n)^2 +n}\geq \frac{1}{(\sqrt{n})^2+n}=\frac{1}{2n}.$ This implies the divergence of the original series.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{n+\ln^2 n} > \frac{1}{an}$$ iff $$n+\ln^2 n < a n$$ iff $$\ln^2 n < (a-1)n$$
which, for sufficiently large $n$, is true if only $a>1$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $\alpha>0$ we have $\log x\le \frac{x^{\alpha}}{\alpha}$.  Therefore, with $\alpha =1/2$ we have

$$\frac{1}{n+\log^2n}\ge\frac{1}{n+4n}=\frac1{5n}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.  - Mark